# I am trying to make a list where all user can go using command BETWEEN, but it doesn't work properly

Tags: postgresql

My code to identified where one user can go works properly, but I want to make a list of where all user can go. And for that I tried using the command **BETWEEN AND**, but it did not work as expected.

Code: Where **ONE USER** can go;

```
SELECT place_name, user_id, user_name
    FROM schema.place, schema.person
    WHERE schema.place_id NOT IN(
        SELECT place_id
            FROM went_to
            WHERE went_to.user_id = 1
            AND age(date) <= interval '4 months'
    )
    AND user_id=1
```

**IMAGE OF THE CODE *WORKING* PROPERLY:**

[image]

> There's a total of 40 lines, places the user with the id 1 can go

Code: Where **ALL USER** can go;

```
SELECT place_name, user_id, user_name
    FROM schema.place, schema.person
    WHERE schema.place_id NOT IN(
        SELECT place_id
            FROM went_to
            WHERE went_to.user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 15
            AND age(date) <= interval '4 months'
    )
    AND user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 15
    ORDER BY user_id
```

**IMAGE OF THE CODE *NOT WORKING* PROPERLY:**

[image]

> It should have a total of 40 lines, places the user with the id 1 can go

When I reduce the difference in the BETWEEN, the code gets closer to the right answer, however it isn't right.

What I am doing it wrong with the **BETWEEN**?

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.place ( 
   place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE schema.user ( 
   user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE schema.visit ( 
   user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   place_id VARCHAR(8),
   data DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES SCHEMA.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES code.place,
        EXCLUDE USING gist (pk_user_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '6 months')::date) WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: SQL results are inherently unordered and you have not put in an `ORDER BY` in your query, so I am not sure that your second example is actually not working. Especially as you  added a `BETWEEN` range for `went_to.id`   Try adding  `ORDER BY user_id, place_name`

Comment: Hi, I just put the order by user_id and the result is the same :(

Comment: What is the relationship between `went_to.id` and `user_id`? Probably good idea to add to your question the table definitions for `place`, `person` and `went_to`.

Comment: went_to.id == user_ id. It woul be better if I wrote like went_to.user_id
But place_id is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the schema would be helpful, but I believe the issue is in how you constructed your query.

```
SELECT place_id
FROM went_to
WHERE went_to.id BETWEEN 1 AND 15
AND age(date) <= interval '4 months'
```

If we look at just the subquery, we are returning all the place ids where users 1-15 went to in the last 4 months. You're then trying to return all places/users that don't match those place ids. The issue is that you're combining all the places that all of those users went to and then using that as an exclusion when you really want to be excluding only places a particular user went to.

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT schema.place.place_name, schema.user.user_id, schema.user.user_name
    FROM schema.place, schema.user
    WHERE (schema.place.place_id, schema.user.user_id) NOT IN(
        SELECT place_id, schema.visit.user_id
            FROM schema.visit
            WHERE schema.visit.user_id::int BETWEEN 1 AND 15
            AND age(data) <= interval '4 months'
    )
    AND user_id::int BETWEEN 1 AND 15
    ORDER BY schema.user.user_id
```

Your schema has the ids as varchars and not ints and the date field is called data, so I had to make some tweaks

Comment: Hello, I will add the SCHEMA :) thanks. But also your solution says that there are to few columns

Comment: I updated my query based on the schema. Try that.

Comment: Actually it needs to be as varchar cause some start with 0, but i created and auto_incriment that I am using was pk. so your solution worked without the tweaks